# Ninject disposes child object before disposing the parent that uses it

Tags: c#, ninject

When I call `IKernel.Dispose()` in the `[TestCleanup]` method of my DataTest, my application is crashing because the first object to be disposed is still in use by another object.

This code reproduces the issue:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Modules;

[TestClass]
public class NinjectDisposeIssue
{
    private IKernel kernel;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel(new Module());
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        kernel.Dispose();
    }

    [DataTestMethod]
    [DataRow]
    [DataRow]
    public void DataTestMethod()
    {
        var parent = kernel.Get<Parent>();

        parent.Run();
    }
}

public class Module : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<Parent>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
        Bind<Service>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
        Bind<Database>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();

        // create 2 workers
        Bind<Worker>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
        Bind<Worker>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    private readonly Service service;
    private readonly IEnumerable<Worker> workers;

    public Parent(Service service, IEnumerable<Worker> workers)
    {
        this.service = service;
        this.workers = workers;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            foreach (var worker in workers)
            {
                worker.StartWork();
            }

            service.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}

public class Service
{
    private readonly Database database;

    public Service(Database database)
    {
        this.database = database;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var value = database.Get();

        // do something with the value
    }
}

public class Worker : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Database database;
    private Task workTask;
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private bool disposedValue;

    public Worker(Database database)
    {
        this.database = database;
    }

    public void StartWork()
    {
        if (workTask == null)
        {
            workTask = Task.Run(WorkLoop);
        }
    }

    private void WorkLoop()
    {
        while (!cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var value = database.Get();

            // do some work with the value...
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                workTask.Wait();
                workTask.Dispose();
            }

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

public class Database : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ThirdPartyDb thirdPartyDb = new ThirdPartyDb();
    private bool disposedValue;

    public string Get()
    {
        return thirdPartyDb.Get("foo");
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                thirdPartyDb.Dispose();
            }

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

public class ThirdPartyDb : IDisposable
{
    private bool isDisposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        isDisposed = true;
    }

    public string Get(string key)
    {
        if (isDisposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(ThirdPartyDb));
        }

        return "bar";
    }
}
```

The `Dispose()` method of the `Database` object is being called before the `Dispose()` method of the 2 `Worker`s.

Question: Is there something I can do in the bindings to force the `Worker`s to be disposed before the `Database` or is the way I have this configured fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution, you can just add another `CancellationTokenSource` to your `Database`. This way you'll make sure that the `thirdPartyDb` is not getting called after disposal.

```
public class Database : IDisposable
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private readonly ThirdPartyDb thirdPartyDb = new ThirdPartyDb();
    private bool disposedValue;

    public string Get()
    {
        if (cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested) return ""; //Return anything acceptable for you

        return thirdPartyDb.Get("foo");
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                thirdPartyDb.Dispose();
            }

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```